# TextRecognize has a memory leak?

Tags: memory, crash, ocr

This code causes Mathematica to slowly accumulate memory until it hard crashes my operating system.  It does this by overwriting OS memory (windows start going black, graphics drivers start crashing etc.)

```
Table[RandomImage[1, {1000, 100}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"] 
// TextRecognize // StringLength, 5000] // Total
```

Compare the above code to this code.  This code does not have a memory leak.

```
Table[RandomImage[1, {1000, 100}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"] 
// ImageMeasurements[#, "Mean"] & , 5000000] // Total
```

I've done enough testing to be pretty confident the issue with this line is with `TextRecognize`.  My "real" application makes a *lot* of `TextRecognize` calls while monitoring computer screens and it always crashes after about an hour of running.  I'd like it to run for at least 24 hours reliably.

I'm running 64 bit Windows 10 with 16GB of RAM.
I have a machine with 128GB of RAM same problem.

Is there a way to force Mathematica to keep the memory usage in check?  Is there an alternative way around this problem?

UPDATE:

Yes this is *stupid* code.  No one actually recognizes text in random data.  But, this allows anyone to reproduce the issue I'm seeing without passing around images.  Copy paste this into your Mathematica install.  Do you see the memory usage grow, so that after half an hour or so you've consumed 32GB of RAM?  That's what I'm seeing.

UPDATE2:

I've demonstrated this issue on two completely separate machines [both Windoze 10, one 32Gig, one 64Gig RAM].  Wolfram Research cannot reproduce this issue on their test machine.  If someone else could confirm this is an issue for themselves, I'd appreciate it.

Update 3:

I realized that for my specific situation, some of the workarounds proposed in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916732/mathematicas-textrecognize-not-up-to-par work great for me.  Cross Correlation is (for me) a vastly superior solution than a buggy TextRecognize.

Comment: You're trying to recognize text in a random image????   No wonder this impossible task is taking forever!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork you misunderstand the problem.  The issue is not time to execute the command.  The issue is that the command consumes unlimited memory, when it's pretty clear that similar commands do not.  There's a clear memory leak in TextRecognize.  That's the issue.

Comment: @John - you should report this to Wolfram Research, in the end they are the ones who can fix this.

Comment: @JasonB. I have already done that, and as of now, I've not been able to get them to admit this is a problem.  I was hoping maybe there were some workarounds available.

Comment: AFAIK `TextRecognize` uses a rather outdated version of Tesseract under the hood. It is not suitable for serious applications. I would recommend using a more up-to-date version, perhaps a Python implementation via `ExternalFunction`. Quick search gives this: https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/.

Comment: But if for some reason you are forced to use `TextRecognize`, as a workaround you could call it in a slave kernel and control the memory usage via `MemoryAvailable[]`, killing the slave kernel when it clearly took up too much memory.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, those are both answers to an implied question.  "Is there a way to work around this problem?"  I've updated my question.  Care to write those out as an answer?

Comment: Related: "[How to TextRecognize a screenshot of code?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/188068/280)"

Comment: "It does this by overwriting OS memory (windows start going black, graphics drivers start crashing etc.)" That is impossible, kernel will just stop any application trying to do so, what is called segfault. No, what happens is that malloc will fail and then return NULL, which would mean no memory and in some cases will cause the Nvidia driver to crash, but not the Kernel, since Kernel has all kind of hacks to not stop working. Chrome just crashes one tab, not all browser.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников, Mathematica has crashed my OS numerous times with this memory leak.  I recommend Googling blue screen of death.  Consider yourself fortunate if you have never experienced it!  Happens more often than it "should."

Comment: Wolfram still has no ability to hijack (or dll inject) into NT kernel of windows. I did experience blue screens, but that is not usually caused by lack of memory, since kernel can just kill some more modern apps and older apps close / free() automatically due to no memory. The usual problem for blue screens for me is nvidia driver. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK `TextRecognize` uses a rather outdated version of Tesseract under the hood. It is not suitable for serious applications. I would recommend using a more up-to-date version, perhaps a Python implementation via `ExternalFunction`. Quick search gives [this](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/).

> Is there a way to force Mathematica to keep the memory usage in check? Is there an alternative way around this problem?

Yes, but you shouldn't rely on `MemoryInUse[]` when working with functionality outside of the *Mathematica*'s kernel, because this function reports memory usage only by the main MathKernel process. To prevent system crashes, it is better to monitor the total free memory available for the operating system using `MemoryAvailable[]`.

If for some reason you are forced to use `TextRecognize`, as a workaround you could call it in a slave kernel and control the memory usage via `MemoryAvailable[]`, killing the slave kernel when it clearly took up too much memory.

A *long time* ago I implemented similar functionality using only low-level functions. A lot has changed since then, but perhaps these old discussions might still be of some interest:

- [Executing code in v.5.2 kernel from within v.7.01 session through MathLink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4983301/590388)
- [How to kill slave kernel securely?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5229294/590388)
- [(MathLink) Correct handling of Messages generated by slave kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4998561/590388)